# How are crawl delays from robots.txt interpreted?

Tags: web-scraping, robots.txt

I am building a python based webscraper that scrapes price and specification data for products from multiple sites.  I want to be respectful and follow the robots.txt as much as I can.

Lets say the crawl delay defined in the robots.txt file is 10 seconds.  How is this interpreted? I built my scraper to go to each product category page and then take the list of all products from each category and then go into each individual product page and scrape price and specifications.

Does each page request need to be delayed by 10 seconds? Or is the act of running my script once considered one action and I just need to wait 10s each time I run it?

If it is the former then how does anyone scrape large amounts of data from a site? If there are 5000 product pages and I delay each one by 10 seconds then my script will take 14hrs for a single run.

What if I split the work between multiple scripts? Does each separate script need to follow the rule by itself or do all requests from a certain IP need to follow the rule collectively?

I don't want to get my IP banned or accidentally take down anyone's site. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: It's interpreted like you interpret it. Just define whether you want to be nice (and ask for an API instead of illegaly scraping content) or be rude (and ignore all rules altogether)

Comment: You don't _need_ to follow the recommended Crawl-Delay (which is not even in the standard), it is just nice to do so. What is your goal here: To be nice to a website? Then it doesn't matter how you spread the task across workers or even IPs, follow it across them. To not be banned? Follow it per IP.

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for replying. Are you saying any scraping is illegal even if i'm following the robots.txt? I was under the impression that was the whole point of that document. To set guidelines for allowable scraping.

Comment: Well, do you have a permission to scrape, aggregate, and use the crawled data? Why not ask the site's owner what he thinks about it?

Comment: @NicoHaase. I'm just a long way off from actually making anything usable and didn't want to ask until i actually think my project will be successful. Also I have no clue yet how much I will have to make requests to the site(s) yet.  I think I'll work on getting everything else sorted on the back end and hold off from scraping and then contact the sites once I know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

It means that you should put a delay of 10 seconds between each of the requests to that particular site. For more information, you can read this article

https://www.contentkingapp.com/academy/robotstxt/#crawl-delay

Preferably, you should use some framework to crawl the sites, like [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). They provide you a download delay option and make sure that the crawling engine delays each request by that much amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've been using beautifulsoup and urlllib. I will look into scrapy.